# Get Text from multiple dynamic generatet Textbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I dynamicly generate some Textboxes and put them into a canvas.

```
        private void create_textbox(int number)
        {
        for(int i = 1; i < number; i++)
            {
            TextBox MyBox = new TextBox();
            darsteller_feld.Name = Convert.ToString("MyBox" + number);
            MyBox.Height = 25;
            MyBox.Width = 250;
            MyBox.Text = "New Box" ;
            MyBox_canvas.Children.Add(MyBox);
            }
        }
```

So i thought i could pt all Texts into a string [] like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
    ARR[i] = ?Unknown_Textbox_Name?.Text;
    }
```

How can i replace the "?Unknown_Textbox_Name?" Part?

Answer (score 2):

Either you save all your textbox in a list when you create them and the just add them to your array.

Or if you want something more generic

U need to find all the childreen inside your canvas using that method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you enumerate over the controls like so

```
foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(MyBox_canvas))
{
    ARR.Add(tb.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use **@Moez Rebai** solution, or, if your `TextBoxes` are direct children of your `Canvas`:

```
var textboxes= MyBox_canvas.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
```

Also, you may want to give each `TextBox` a nema, to distinguish them later:

```
MyBox.Name = "MyTextBox"+i;
```